# How to get data from a complicated object / array structure?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get data from a complicated API structure. How would I get all the image from the following objects and arrays:

```
const x = { cars: [ 
    { types: 
      { 
        name: "VW", 
        image: [{ url: "http://www.lkjl.com" }] 
      } 
    }, 
    {...}, 
    {...} 
]};
```

[image: cars object]

I know I can get the image url like this:

```
x.cars[0].types.image[0].url
```

But how can I print out all the image urls?

```
x.cars.map(item => {
   return(
       item.image[0].url; // this is wrong
   );
});
```

Do I need to have another map inside the map function?

Comment: Please post the return object so we can see how the image fits in.

Comment: there will be multiple images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with mapping the `url` property.

```js
const
    x = { cars: [{ types: { name: "VW", image: [{ url: "http://www.lkjl.com" },{ url: "http://www.alkjl.com" }] } }, { types: { name: "Tata", image: [{ url: "http://www.lskal.com" },{ url: "http://www.lkfjl.com" }] } }] },
    images = x.cars.reduce((r, item) => r.concat(item.types.image.map(i => i.url)), []);

console.log(images);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed `types`:

```
x.cars.map(item => {
   return(
       item.types.image[0].url;
   );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you missed to access the 'types' object  in your map function 
it should be like this :

```
x.cars.map(item => {
   return(
       item.types.image[0].url; //this should work for you
   );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the `cars` array you have `image` array inside the `types` object, So you have to iterate over both the arrays to print out all the images.

See the code below.

```js
const x = { cars: [ 
    { types: 
      { 
        name: "VW", 
        image: [{ url: "http://www.lkjl.com" }] 
      } 
    }, 
    { types: 
      { 
        name: "VW", 
        image: [{ url: "http://www.lkjl12.com" }] 
      } 
    }
]};

x.cars.forEach(car => {
  car.types.image.forEach( i => console.log(i.url));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

x.cars.map(item => item.types.image[0].url)

Answer (score -1):

have you try this way ?

```
x.cars.map((item, key) => {
 return(
   item.types.image[0].url;
  //you're missing 'types'
 );
});
```

i hope it can help you.

Comment: Makes no sense. Index of `image` array has nothing to do with index of `cars` array